# Laravel validation methods

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I try to give access to users to change(update) their info in their panel also i want let them to change their email address as well as their password but to be optional, for example they maybe just want to change their names and not to change email address or password what is the validation method for that?

my validate currently is this but will return error that the email address is the same:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $this->validate($request, array(
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email' => 'nullable|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'gender' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'nullable|string|min:6|confirmed',
            ));

        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $user->password = $request->input('password');

        $user->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Your information was successfully updated.');

        return redirect()->route('users.list', $user->id);
    }
```

Comment: remove unique:users

Comment: @BilalAhmed This is not something stable. Removing an important rule like that is not a good option.

Comment: No one to do that. You have to create another page for update email address

Comment: @BilalAhmed with deleting unique:users my problem will be solve but how if they use other users email? `kristoff` i edit users info in their profile should i make other page? and why?

Comment: 'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,'.$id,// validate for unique email except the existing id please check answer now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique), You can ignore the current user's email address in validation:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)
```

If your table uses a primary key column name other than id, you may specify the name of the column when calling the ignore method:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id')
```

So,

```
   $this->validate($request, array(
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => [
            'required','nullable','string','email','max:255',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
        ],
        'gender' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'nullable|string|min:6|confirmed',

    ));
```

Comment: can you share complete code please? a bit confusing. and if i ignore it how about when they want to edit it? then still will be ignore?

Comment: all are as it is. just change `'email'` rule and ignoring this specific email address is only for validation, doesnot effect anything else.

Comment: return error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Rule' not found`

Comment: this is not a wrong logic, infact it's the only right logic. and you have to add the namespace `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

Answer (score 0):

Your user update it should be like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $this->validate($request, array(
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'gender' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'nullable|string|min:6|confirmed',
            ));

        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $user->password = $request->input('password');

        $user->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Your information was successfully updated.');

        return redirect()->route('users.list', $user->id);
    }
```

then you have to create new page for update new address.

Comment: why you delete email field validator?! like this they even can use non email just text or make it empty!

Comment: when you allow user to register you should already check the email address  unique ? right ? if the user just update and then changed new address email why you need to check valid from register ?

Comment: to be sure that new email address is email address as well and not a simple text or and empty field. force them to change email with email only.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to below for name field validation only:

```
 $this->validate($request, array(
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,'.$id,//validate for unique email except this id
            'gender' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ));
```

Comment: no man! i need validate other fields as well when i let them to edit i want make them change their info with valid data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->validate($request, array(
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email' => 'nullable|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,id,'.$userId,
                'gender' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'nullable|string|min:6|confirmed',
            ));
```

$userId is id of users table of given user

Unique takes 4 params
unique:table,column,except,idColumn

table -> tableName

column -> uniqueColumnName

except -> exclude column name

idColumn -> value of exclude column

Comment: Undefined variable: userId

Comment: change $userId to $id